# How to make Regular expression into non-greedy?

Tags: javascript, regex, filter, expression, regex-greedy

I'm using jQuery. I have a string with a block of special characters (begin and end). I want get the text from that special characters block. I used a regular expression object for in-string finding. But how can I tell jQuery to find multiple results when have two special character or more?

My HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="textcontainer">
     Cuộc chiến pháp lý giữa [|cơ thử|nghiệm|] thị trường [|test2|đây là test lần 2|] chứng khoán [|Mỹ|day la nuoc my|] và ngân hàng đầu tư quyền lực nhất Phố Wall mới chỉ bắt đầu.
    </div>
</div>
```

and my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var takedata = $("#textcontainer").text();
  var test = 'abcd adddb';
  var filterdata = takedata.match(/(\[.+\])/);

  alert(filterdata); 

  //end write js 
});
```

My result is: **[|cơ thử|nghiệm|] thị trường [|test2|đây là test lần 2|] chứng khoán [|Mỹ|day la nuoc my|]** . But this isn't the result I want :(. How to get [text] for times 1 and [demo] for times 2 ?

---

I've just done my work after searching info on internet ^^. I make code like this:

```
var filterdata = takedata.match(/(\[.*?\])/g);
```

- my result is : **[|cơ thử|nghiệm|],[|test2|đây là test lần 2|]**
  this is right!. but I don't really understand this. Can you answer my why?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36680788/14928633) answer helps me.

Answer (score 635, accepted):

The non-greedy regex modifiers are like their greedy counter-parts but with a `?` immediately following them:

```
*  - zero or more
*? - zero or more (non-greedy)
+  - one or more
+? - one or more (non-greedy)
?  - zero or one
?? - zero or one (non-greedy)
```

Comment: might be useful to note that `?` on its own means 'one or zero' (but is greedy!). E.g. `'bb'.replace(/b?/, 'a') //'ab'` and `'bb'.replace(/c?/, 'a') //'abb'`

Comment: how did c match nothing there

Comment: @MuhammadUmer I think he was suggesting that because the `c` won't match, but you have the `?`, which is `0 or 1`, then it's going to match `0 number of c characters`, hence replacing it. I have no idea how it works though, because that doesn't compile in any regex engine i've tried 

Comment: If you still need to support MSIE 11 it's good to know that it doesn't support the `s` flag for the rexexp – I first thought that MSIE doesn't support non-greedy modifiers but the real cause was the `s` flag in my regexp.

Comment: What exactly would be the difference between *?* and *??*? I somehow can't see the distinction between greedy and non-greedy *zero-or-one* matching condition. Help me understand.

Comment: @KonradViltersten it's to do with capturing. Eg. `'abcd'.match(/(a)?b??(.*)/)` will produce capture groups `a` and `bcd` because it matches the `b` lazily so `b` gets included into the greedy `.*` match. Without the double `?` it would only produce capture groups `a` and `cd` because the `b` gets consumed before the capture starts.

Answer (score 47):

You are right that greediness is an issue:

```
--A--Z--A--Z--
  ^^^^^^^^^^
     A.*Z
```

If you want to match both `A--Z`, you'd have to use `A.*?Z` (the `?` makes the `*` "reluctant", or lazy).

There are sometimes better ways to do this, though, e.g.

```
A[^Z]*+Z
```

This uses negated character class and possessive quantifier, to reduce backtracking, and is likely to be more efficient.

In your case, the regex would be:

```
/(\[[^\]]++\])/
```

**Unfortunately** Javascript regex doesn't support possessive quantifier, so you'd just have to do with:

```
/(\[[^\]]+\])/
```

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

  - See: *An Alternative to Laziness*

    - [Possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)
  - [Flavors comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)

---

### Quick summary

```
*   Zero or more, greedy
*?  Zero or more, reluctant
*+  Zero or more, possessive

+   One or more, greedy
+?  One or more, reluctant
++  One or more, possessive

?   Zero or one, greedy
??  Zero or one, reluctant
?+  Zero or one, possessive
```

Note that the reluctant and possessive quantifiers are also applicable to the finite repetition `{n,m}` constructs.

Examples in Java:

```
System.out.println("aAoZbAoZc".replaceAll("A.*Z", "!"));  // prints "a!c"
System.out.println("aAoZbAoZc".replaceAll("A.*?Z", "!")); // prints "a!b!c"

System.out.println("xxxxxx".replaceAll("x{3,5}", "Y"));  // prints "Yx"
System.out.println("xxxxxx".replaceAll("x{3,5}?", "Y")); // prints "YY"
```

Comment: i copy your regex into my work and result is : 
invalid quantifier +\\])
[Break on this error] var filterdata = takedata.match(/(\\[[^\\]]++\\])/);\n (firebugs + Firefox)

something wrong ?

Comment: @Rueta: apparently Javascript flavor doesn't support possessive. I've edited my answer to reflect this fact. You can just use one `+` instead of two.

Comment: Though atomic groups can be used in place of possessive quantifiers, JavaScript does not support the atomic groups either. But there is a third alternative, see this: http://instanceof.me/post/52245507631/regex-emulate-atomic-grouping-with-lookahead - `you can emulate atomic grouping with LookAhead. (?>a) becomes (?=(a))\1`

Comment: This is a Java answer for a JavaScript question and Java != JavaScript. Readers, take note.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it would be like this

```
takedata.match(/(\[.+\])/g);
```

the `g` at the end means global, so it doesn't stop at the first match.

Comment: yea, you are right in /g. i've just done my work with your answer /g ^^. 

But when i make regular /(\\[.+\\])/g my result is :
[|cơ thử|nghiệm|] thị trường [|test2|đây là test lần 2|] chứng khoán [|Mỹ|day la nuoc my|] :(