# regex to match between <tr> tags matches between only first and last <tr> in the table

Tags: javascript, regex

I would expect this regular expression to match all ten `<tr></tr>` combinations (along with everything in between, given an HTML table.

`var re = /<tr>.*<\/tr>/g`;

But the entire string is matched. Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/zL6Qx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use non-greedy matching regex:

```
var re = /<tr>.*?<\/tr>/g;
```

Comment: I thought is was something like that, thank you. But how does the question mark at the the end define its greediness?

Comment: @thomas this is the syntax for it, see this thread for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824302/how-to-make-regular-expression-into-non-greedy