# Regex grabbing too much text

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

Let's say I have the following text :

```
foo bar baz <!-- USERNAME --> <!-- ACCESS_KEY --> baz bar foo

<!--:USERNAME-->

<!-- eueuteh -->

 -DarchetypeVersion=<!-- java-version --> -UserName=<!-- :USERNAME --> -DsauceAccessKey=<!-- ACCESS_KEY -->
```

What I want to do is replace `<!-- USERNAME -->` with some other text. Unfortunately the regex I've created doesn't actually work as intended, and for example replaces the whole `<!-- java-version --> -UserName=<!-- :USERNAME -->` expression. The first two occurences are replaced properly. Where is the mistake ?

Here's what I've got, testing in javascript console :

```
var re = new RegExp('(<!--)(.)*(USERNAME)(.)?(-->)');
```

Comment: The problem is with your `(.)*`, that means: match with anything, 0 or more times and it matches with `java-version --> -UserName=<!-- :`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make Regular expression into non-greedy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824302/how-to-make-regular-expression-into-non-greedy)

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? http://regex101.com/r/lI8cV8

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis please post you're comment as an answer, as right now it's the only one actually working :) thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the below technique with things like HTML, XML and similar, (even though it is bad practice when it comes to nested content)

### Regex

`(<[^>]*)(USERNAME)([^>]*>)`

---

### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/lI8cV8

Answer (score 4):

The correct expression appears to be

```
/<!--(.(?!-->))*USERNAME.*?-->/g
```