# Javascript global regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get a regular expression working, using javascript. It should match the following format, and I want to find it globaly in the following string:

```
[[foo=bar:something]]
```

`foo`, `bar` and `something` can be any alphanumeric characters.

The expression I tried, is the following (the lots of `\s*` is for matching parts with unintentional whitespaces):

```
var string = "something [[abc=foo:bar]] some other stuff [[foo=bar:abc]] else";
var regex = new RegExp("\\[\\[\s*.+\s*=\s*.+\s*:\s*.+\s*\\]\\]", "g");
console.log(string.match(regex));
```

Which gives me:

```
[  "[[abc=foo:bar]] some other stuff [[foo=bar:abc]]"  ]
```

As the single match.

My question is, how could i match only this pattern, and not only the stuff between the first and last `[[` and `]]`, and get this result:

```
[  "[[abc=foo:bar]]", "[[foo=bar:abc]]"  ]
```

Comment: `.+` will consume character greedily. Quick solution would be to change them to `.+?`, but that would not be a rigid solution.

Comment: thanks, that did the trick! Could you explain in a few words, what the ? did at the end?

Comment: `.+` is going to give you any "non-whitespace" character, which includes a LOT more than alphanumerics.  `\w+` would match "word characters", which are alphanumerics and the underscore character (`_`) . . . if the underscore is not acceptable, then you will need to use `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` (or, if you are okay with the regex being case-insensitive, you could use `[a-z0-9]+` and include the `i` flag).

Comment: It makes the quantifier lazy, so it will try to consume least number of character while matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands right now, you've got a lot of extraneous matching going on here. All of the `\s*` can just be removed, since you've already got `.+` in there.

This is functionally equivalent to what you currently have, mostly since you're not capturing any of the matches right now:

```
var string = "something [[abc=foo:bar]] some other stuff [[foo=bar:abc]] else";
var regex = new RegExp("\\[\\[.+=.+:.+\\]\\]", "g");
console.log(string.match(regex));
```

What your question is asking for is for your regex to be "non-greedy," or "lazy," which means you want it to stop at the first match each time. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824302/how-to-make-regular-expression-into-non-greedy) or [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) for more help on that.

tl;dr is *You should change your wildcards to* `.+?`

```
var string = "something [[abc=foo:bar]] some other stuff [[foo=bar:abc]] else";
var regex = /\[\[.+?=.+?:.+?\]\]/g
console.log(string.match(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\[\[\s*\w+\s*=\s*\w+\s*:\s*\w+\s*\]\]
```

That regex should work for what you're doing.  The problem was the `.+` was matching everything in the rest of the string.  You needed to make a character set that would match everything up until the equal sign without consuming it, and `\w` (which is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`) does just that.

Comment: Works when I tested it at regexpal.com

Comment: thank you Samuel, but with charlieg's answer it was easier to group the words, and extract them

Comment: My result was retaining the greedy algorithm, but whichever one is easier for you will work fine.

Comment: You can't write `[\w^=]` if you want to allow word characters and exclude `=`! The `^` is only seen as special character at the start of a character class, otherwise, it is a simple literal. You can replace it by: `[^\W=]`

Comment: Hmm.  Thanks.  Not really warmed up on my regexes.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: `\w` by default does not match `=`, so the whole `[^\W=]` is equivalent to `\w`

Answer (score 0):

You already got an answer, so short:
`.*` is generally a bad idea. Try to be more specific if you can:

```
var regex = /\[\[[^=]+=[^:]+:[^\]]+\]\]/g
```

Asking for "all but the next expectad character" reduces the tracebacks when nothing is found.