# Ruby Regex non-greedy match: looking for the closest occurrence of a phrase left to a searched word

Tags: ruby, regex

Lets say I have the following string: `"BENffew123X\r\nBENx432f456X\r\nBEN!233789X\r\nBEN4545789X"`
I want to have a regex that will catch "BEN!233789", it has to lookup non-greedily for "BEN", followed by any character (excluding the word "BEN") and ending with 789X. I tried the regex: `/BEN.+?789X/mi`and I get `"BENffew123X\r\nBENx432f456X\r\nBEN!233789X"` as a match.
I understand that this regex looks for the first "BEN" and catches the start of the string, but I want it to look for the "BEN" which is closest to the first "789X". How can I achieve that? One Idea is to reverse the string, should I do it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to make sure that `BEN` isn't present in the text between `BEN` and `789X`. You can do this using a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/BEN(?:(?!BEN).)*?789X/mi
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/zM5pP9).

**Explanation:**

```
BEN      # Match "BEN"
(?:      # Start of non-capturing group that matches...
 (?!BEN) # (if "BEN" can't be matched here)
 .       # any character
)*?      # Repeat any number of times, as few as possible
789X     # Match 789X
```

Comment: What does `*?` mean ?

Comment: Non-greedy `*` (as comment says 'as few as possible').

Comment: @ArupRakshit: "Zero or more repetitions (`*`), as few as possible (`?`)". So if you have `BEN...789X...789X` it will stop the match at the first `789X`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks. I understand now from this - [how to make Regular expression into non-greedy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824302/how-to-make-regular-expression-into-non-greedy)

Comment: Wrapping the negative lookahead in a non-capturing group is a really great idea -- especially if, like me, you're fixing a bug in an existing system and the later logic depends on the exact set of captures. Have an upvote!