# Regular Expression: exclude html tags from "content"

Tags: javascript, regex

One friend asked me this and as my knowledge on RegExp is not so good yet here I am.

How can exclude the HTML tags from this string?

```
re<br>na<br>to<br>galvao
```

I've tried some RegExp but it didn't work as I was expecting.

```
(.*)<.*>(.*)
```

But this RegExp gets the first < and the last >.

Any ideas?

Comment: This won't be enough without a real parser because you'll still have ```script```, ```style```, ```object```, etc. tags with content in them.

Comment: This is easy to answer, you shouldn't use regex for that at all.'

Comment: This is what you should be doing -> http://jsfiddle.net/Hpe5M/

Comment: @adeneo Exactly what I thought when I started reading this question. Not a big deal, but I usually use `d.textContent || d.innerText` (flip-flopped the properties) because I hope the majority of people would use a browser that supports `textContent`, therefore not doing an unnecessary check with `innerText`. Again, not a big deal. Seriously though, post this as an answer

Comment: @Ian - I wrote that pretty quick, but now that I think about it, your way is how it should be done, and how I usually do it. `innerText` has good support, but it triggers a reflow, which `textContent` does not, that's why `textContent` is preferred. And I didn't post as an answer because the OP specifically is asking for regex.

Comment: @adeneo Hey, I was just pointing it out! I thought you wrote it fast, and even if you didn't, I still just wanted to say something small. I didn't know about the reflow actually. As I read the MDN docs for `textContent`, I now see the fine print. I thought IE created `innerText` awhile ago and has always supported it, where some browsers have adopted it just because. But `textContent` is a standard and is supported by almost all browsers, except old IE. I see why you didn't create the answer, but I feel like this is one of the perfect situations to post the *right* way.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. My question here was mainly for learning purposes.

This was not a real problem, but thanks anyway for everyone.

Comment: No problem, noone linked to the classic answer that always comes up when someone posts something like this, so I will, again pointing out that you should ***never*** use regex to parse HTML. [Here it comes do not fi​ght ̕h̵i​s un̨ho͞ly radiańcé destro҉ying all enli̍̈́̂̈́ghtenment, HTML tags lea͠ki̧n͘g fr̶ǫm ̡yo​͟ur eye͢s̸ ̛l̕ik͏e liq​uid pain, ̅ͫ͏̙̤ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: What are these strange characters on the answer?

And I read the answer but I just can't agree totally with this argument that I **never** should use regexp with HTML.

EDIT:
I think it depends on the application, if you have control of the source code and other possible variables.

Comment: @RenatoGalvão The point is that using regular expressions to parse HTML isn't 100% reliable, while DOM methods basically are. I honestly can't think of a problem/situation where regular expressions can solve it but DOM methods can't do it more reliably.

Comment: there are plenty of situations when regex can do the job just fine. Like... this one.  regex's shortcomings with DOM have to do with actual parsing, like validating or traversing properly.  Simple stuff like just stripping all tags is easy and regex can most definitely do it easily.  Too many people jump on the "oh nohs, someone mentioned regex and html in the same sentence, burn the witch!" bandwagon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a quick way to do it:

```
var content = "re<br>na<br>to<br>galvao";
content = content.replace(/<[^>]*>/g,'');
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a non-greedy match. According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824302/how-to-make-regular-expression-into-non-greedy), in javascript it is *?

So, assuming this is the only problem with your regex, it should work with

```
(.*?)<.*?>(.*?)
```

Answer (score 2):

Match all html tags with this regex:

```
 <("[^"]*?"|'[^']*?'|[^'">])*>
```

see demo here: http://regex101.com/r/fA0oT4