# Character count in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

In html, how to count the real characters shown in a innerHTML?

For example, In `<strong>Hi</strong>`, the # of characters should be 2, not 19.

I've tried 2 methods which do not work:

1. `str.length` - This will include `<>` characters.
2. `getElementById` - This will include `<>` characters:

I tried as follows:

```
elem_output = document.getElementById("example_id"); 
elem_output.innerText.length;//1st
elem_output.textContent.length;//2nd
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know which element has `#example_id` in your code, but `element.innerText.length` should work.

**Edit:** Other answers suggest the use of `textContent` instead of `innerText`. I think that depending on OP's real needs one or the other (or even `innerHTML`, which appears in question's title) could be suitable. So, I'd suggest to read carefully the differences between those properties in the docs:

- [Differences between `innerText` and `textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText)
- [Diferences between `innerHTML` and `textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerHTML)

**Edit 2**: OP's question says *real characters **shown** in a innerHTML*, so I'd go with `innerText` since:

> `innerText` is aware of style and will not return the text of hidden elements, whereas `textContent` will.

```js
var tag = document.getElementById('test');
console.log(tag.innerText.length)
```

```html
<strong id="test">Hi</strong>
```

Comment: Great, thanks. This works! I should not use `elem_output.innerText.length | elem_output.textContent.length;` only the `elem_output.innerText.length` part is enough.

Comment: Sure. `|` is the [bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR) operator, and it doesn't make any sense to me on your code...

Answer (score 1):

```js
var html='<div>div1</div><div>div2</div>';
console.log( 
    html.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '').length
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var p=document.createElement("p")
p.innerHTML="<strong>Hi</strong>"
alert(p.querySelector("strong").innerHTML.length)
```

If you have data in html then you can also try following

```js
alert(document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[0].innerText.length);
//Or
alert(document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[0].innerHTML.length);
//Or
alert(document.querySelector("strong").innerHTML.length);
//Or
alert(document.querySelector("strong").innerText.length);
```

```html
<strong>Hi</strong>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there can be a lot of different html tags within your text so there's three way of doing things

If you need to use **regex** to filter specific tags then **innerHTML** would be the way to get what you need.

```js
var exampleid = document.getElementById('example_id').innerHTML;
exampleid = exampleid.replace(/<[^>]strong>/g, ""); 
alert(exampleid.length + ' characters.');
```

```html
<div id="example_id">hi, <strong>I'm bold and my tags are ignored</strong> while <i>I'm Italic but my tags are counted</i>.</div>
```

See : [Regular Expression: exclude html tags from "content"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259540/regular-expression-exclude-html-tags-from-content)

---

If you wish to ingore all tags then use `innerText` or `textContent`.

**innerText** :

```js
var exampleid = document.getElementById('example_id').innerText.length;
alert(exampleid + ' characters.');
```

```html
<div id="example_id">hi, <strong>I'm bold</strong> while <i>I'm Italic</i>.</div>
```

**textContent** (careful [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) a W3C standard, it is not supported by IE < 9) :

```js
var exampleid = document.getElementById('example_id').textContent.length;
alert(exampleid + ' characters.');
```

```html
<div id="example_id">hi, <strong>I'm bold</strong> while <i>I'm Italic</i>.</div>
```

Learn more on the differences between all these : [Difference between innerText and innerHTML in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml-in-javascript)

Comment: There's absolutely no need for this. Both `innerText` and `textContent` get **rendered text** for the node and its children. Check the console on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jordinebot/u1okch3k/)

Comment: @JordiNebot Thanks for your comment, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about this for `<strong>Hi</strong>`

```
document.getElementsByTagName("strong").innerText.length;
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` returns a nodeList , not a single element

Comment: @charlietfl yes you're ri8, I thought there is only one `strong` element

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

```
var element = document.querySelector('#some-element');
var length = element.textContent.length;
```

It's the simplest and elegant solution.

Comment: Hash symbol `#` shoudn't be in your ID name when using `document.getElementById()`