# Java Regex for first matching String

Tags: java, regex

I have a string `hhht`. I need to grep `12121212` & `56565656` from the string. What i tried so far is shown below.

```
String hhht = "dhdhdh<a:Rakesh>12121212</a:Rakesh>sdsdvsdvsvvsv"+"sfsf"+"<a:Rakesh>56565656</a:Rakesh>zvnbjvbj";

Pattern pattern    = Pattern.compile("<a:Rakesh>(.+)</a:Rakesh>");
Matcher matcher    = pattern.matcher(hhht);

for(int hh = 0 ;hh <matcher.groupCount(); hh++){
    if(matcher.find())
        System.out.println(matcher.group(hh+1));

}
```

I got the output as,

```
12121212</a:Rakesh>sdsdvsdvsvvsvsfsf<a:Rakesh>56565656
```

i.e, the pattern is matching to the first `<a:Rakesh>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a greedy matcher which is not limited to matching numbers. This means that it will match *as much as possible*. Since you have two matching tags it grabs every character between the opening of the first tag and the closing of the second tag.

You can make it non greedy (it will then stop as early as possible, stopping at the first `</a:Rakesh>`) or make it only match numbers (which will not match `</a:Rakesh>`, stopping at that point).

This matches only numbers:

```
"<a:Rakesh>(\\d+)</a:Rakesh>"
```

This is the non greedy approach:

```
"<a:Rakesh>(.+?)</a:Rakesh>"
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Use non-greedy regex with `DOTALL` flag:

   ```
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)<a:Rakesh>(.+?)</a:Rakesh>");
   ```
2. And you cannot get `matcher.groupCount()` before calling `find`

Use it like this

```
if(matcher.find()) {
   for(int hh = 0; hh <= matcher.groupCount(); hh++){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(hh+1));    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on greeding matching:
Take this pattern:

```
Pattern pattern    = Pattern.compile("<a:Rakesh>(.+?)</a:Rakesh>");
```

For more information [look this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824302/how-to-make-regular-expression-into-non-greedy).

And you should use a while loop:

```
    while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));

    }
```