# python regex how to avoid match multiple semicolon?

Tags: regex, logstash

I'm about to write a regex to extract substrings. the string is:

> `ASP.NET_SessionId=frffcjcarie4dhxouz5yklwu;+BIGipServercapitaliq-ssl=3617221783.36895.0000;+ObSSOCookie=wkyQfn2Cyx2%2f7kSj4zBB886WaLs92Ord9FSf64c%2byHFOBwgEP4f3UmorDj051suQwRXAKEwBtYVKRYJuUGh2YNZtAj2%2bNp8asLIT9xQPqVktEAzkl3jNIv8MyWFsoFPDtm%2fTm1FeaCP%2bGTk9Oa%2fCNA0Hmy847qK2qo7%2bbziV%2bjeClbkGjAX3pgcPzfs%2bQp7p9BSjP1xJqUaUKwJ2%2flIgzZL5Ma%2bnJK8j%2b732ixNyIDNDGo7uIF%2b;+machineIdCookie=866873600;+userLoggedIn=jga;sdgjefdfdfs`

I want to extract a substring beginning with `ObSSOCookie=....;` and ending just before the `userLoggedIn`.

I set my regex pattern

```
pattern = "ObSSOCookie=.*;"
```

But it continues to extract until the **last** semicolon (which includes the `+machineIdCookie=866873600`), rather than the **first** semicolon, which is what I want.

Is there a way to just extract up to the first semicolon? And I can't just use `split` by ";" cause this regex is actually to be used in a `Logstash` configuration file and there's no way to use python-style coding there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just grab anything except the next `;` like this ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/pG3lJ5/1))

```
 ObSSOCookie=([^;]*)


>>> import re
>>> data = 'ASP.NET_SessionId=frffcjcarie4dhxouz5yklwu;+BIGipServercapitaliq-ssl=3617221783.36895.0000;+ObSSOCookie=wkyQfn2Cyx2%2f7kSj4zBB886WaLs92Ord9FSf64c%2byHFOBwgEP4f3UmorDj051suQwRXAKEwBtYVKRYJuUGh2YNZtAj2%2bNp8asLIT9xQPqVktEAzkl3jNIv8MyWFsoFPDtm%2fTm1FeaCP%2bGTk9Oa%2fCNA0Hmy847qK2qo7%2bbziV%2bjeClbkGjAX3pgcPzfs%2bQp7p9BSjP1xJqUaUKwJ2%2flIgzZL5Ma%2bnJK8j%2b732ixNyIDNDGo7uIF%2b;+machineIdCookie=866873600;+userLoggedIn=jga;sdgjefdfdfs'
>>> p = re.compile('ObSSOCookie=([^;]*)')
>>> m = p.search(data)
>>> m.group(1)
'wkyQfn2Cyx2%2f7kSj4zBB886WaLs92Ord9FSf64c%2byHFOBwgEP4f3UmorDj051suQwRXAKEwBtYVKRYJuUGh2YNZtAj2%2bNp8asLIT9xQPqVktEAzkl3jNIv8MyWFsoFPDtm%2fTm1FeaCP%2bGTk9Oa%2fCNA0Hmy847qK2qo7%2bbziV%2bjeClbkGjAX3pgcPzfs%2bQp7p9BSjP1xJqUaUKwJ2%2flIgzZL5Ma%2bnJK8j%2b732ixNyIDNDGo7uIF%2b'
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to make your regex non-greedy

Instead of using this

```
*  - zero or more
```

Use this

```
*? - zero or more (non-greedy)
```

Here's your expression ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/jN7dG5/1)).

```
ObSSOCookie=(.*?;)
```

This is a general technique, also described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2824314).