# Retrieve p content using a JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have got this far `/( *)<pre ([^>]+)>([\s\S]*)<\/pre>/g` but this fails with something like this:

```
<p>
  Hello
</p>
<p>
  World
</p>
```

`$3` will be

```
  Hello
</p>
<p>
  World
```

What I want is

```
  Hello
```

Any help?

**Before you downvote, I am not trying to manipulate the DOM with a regexp, I am writing tiny script that fixes the indentation.**

Comment: This is unlikely to be the right approach for whatever you're trying to do. (There's a famous StackOverflow answer on this subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454. It's written melodramatically, but there's definitely a solid core of truth in there.)

Comment: Your problem is that your regex is greedy. You can add a `?` to most things regex to make them non-greedy `*` is greedy, `*?` is non-greedy. So `((.|[\n\r])*?)` should do the trick. ruakh is correct though!

Comment: The problem is that I am trying to do weird formatting si it has to be with regexp! @ippi `( *)<pre ([^>]+)>((.|[\n\r])*?)<\/pre>` works as expected, if you add it as answer I'll mark as correct

Comment: Alright, what won't I do for them internet points?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, I am not trying to manipulate the DOM with a regexp, I writing tiny script that fixes indentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is that your regex is greedy. You can add a `?` to most things regex to make them non-greedy. `*` is greedy, `*?` is non-greedy. So `((.|[\n\r])*?)` should do the trick. (ruakh is correct though!)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2824314/1497533

Comment: `((.|[\n\r])*?)` will do the trick, but it's technically incorrect (`\r` and `\n` are not the only line separator characters) and needlessly inefficient (using alternation where a character class will serve).  `([\s\S]*?)` is what you should use.