# Javascript regular expressions modifier U

Tags: javascript, regex, non-greedy

I have a string

"{1} {2} {4} {abc} {abs}"

and the regular expression

```
/\{(.+)\}/g
```

In PHP regular expressions i can use modifier "**U**" (*U modifier: Ungreedy. The match becomes lazy by default*). If i use `/\{(.+)\}/gU` my response looks like this:

**Array (5) [ "1", "2", "4", "abc", "abs" ]**

In javascript no modifier U. Without this modifier my response looks like this:

**Array (1) [ "1 2 4 abc abs" ]**

How i can do this?

Comment: `.+?`... There's no option to do it by default but you can always do it manually...

Comment: Is expected result `Array (5) [ "1", "2", "4", "abc", "abs" ]` ?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes ....!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to make the `+` ungreedy by adding the `?` modifier:

```
"{1} {2} {4} {abc} {abs}".match(/\{(.+?)\}/g)
```

Another way would be to replace `.` with "anything except closing brace":

```
"{1} {2} {4} {abc} {abs}".match(/\{([^}]+)\}/g)
```

Comment: Why did you escape `{` character in your pattern? I think that's useless. https://regex101.com/r/eW0dF3/1

Comment: @Shafizadeh: I copy/pasted from the question. Useless but also harmless.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all `{`s and explode the string per `}`. Something like this:

```js
var str = "{1} {2} {4} {abc} {abs}";
var result = str.replace(/{|}$/g,"").split(/} ?/);
document.write(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `RegExp` `/([a-z]+|\d+)(?=\})/ig` to match `a-z` case insensitive or digit characters followed by `}`

```
"{1} {2} {4} {abc} {abs}".match(/([a-z]+|\d+)(?=\})/ig)
```

```js
console.log("{1} {2} {4} {abc} {abs}".match(/([a-z]+|\d+)(?=\})/ig))
```

Comment: I think your pattern could be simply this `/(\w+)(?=})/g`. You don't need to escape `{` character, Also what OP mentioned in his question is just an example. I guess there maybe are some values like these: `1a`, `ba3`.