# How detect multiple listings within a text using regular expression?

Tags: regex, java-8

I'm currently trying to detect any listings within a text, given by the user. I seem to fail in properly detecting those listings with a regular expression.

**Example Text**

```
a, b, c and d, or e
```

**Rule Set**

```
\w+(,?\s*\w+)+,?\s*(and|or)
```

Starting with one word on the left side suffices for my use case (denoted by the first `\w+`). Using [Regular Expressions 101](https://regex101.com/) to test the regular expression, shows that it works just fine with the example text above.

Using Java's `Matcher` class, I can simply check for the *last group* whether it is an *and* or *or*, to detect the "type" of the conjunction (so to speak).

However, a more complex input will cause a false detection of the listings. That is, multiple listings are detected as *one* rather than *multiple*.

**Multiple Listings Example**

```
a, b, c and d, or e but not f, g, h and i, or j
```

Again, testing with [Regular Expressions 101](https://regex101.com/) only one listing is detected (reaching from the start of the text until the very last *or*).

So, how would I alter the regular expression to detect multiple listings rather than all listings as one?

Also, I'm fine with any other solution, too. I just would like to solve this as clean as possible.

---

Finally, have some code to see an example implementation.

**Main**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\w+(,?\\s*\\w+)+,?\\s*(and|or)").matcher("a, b, c and d, or e but not f, g, h and i, or j");

        while(matcher.find()){
            String conjunctionType = matcher.group(matcher.groupCount()).toLowerCase();

            Arrays.asList(Conjunction.values()).forEach(type -> {
                if(conjunctionType.equals(type.toString())){
                    System.out.println("Type: " + type);
                    System.out.println("Match: " + matcher.group());
                    // TODO: use the type for further processing
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Conjunction Enum**

```
public enum Conjunction {
    AND,
    OR;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.name().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Type: or
Match: a, b, c and d, or e but not f, g, h and i, or
```

**Desired Output**

```
Type: or
Match: a, b, c and d, or
Type: or
Match: f, g, h and i, or
```

---

**Update**

I forgot to mention that any single letter in the regular expressions above are mere placeholders for any arbitrary amount of words.

**An Even More Complex Example**

```
a, b with some other words, c and d , or e but not f, g, h or i, and j
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution by making the regular expression partially non-greedy.

```
(\b\w+\b\s*,??\s*)+, (or|and)
```

Note the `??` in the regular expression (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2824314/6656268) for more information). See [this example](https://regex101.com/r/oZkhmv/1) for the final result. While ignoring the last "item" of the listings, this is sufficient for my use case.

**Example Code**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "a, b, c and d, or e but not f, g, h and i, or j";
        String pattern = "(\\b\\w+\\b\\s*,??\\s*)+, (or|and)";      

        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(text);

        while(matcher.find()){
            String conjunctionType = matcher.group(matcher.groupCount()).toLowerCase();

            Arrays.asList(Conjunction.values()).forEach(type -> {
                if(conjunctionType.equals(type.toString())){
                    System.out.println("Type: " + type);
                    System.out.println("Match: " + matcher.group());
                    // TODO: use the type for further processing
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Type: or
Match: a, b, c and d, or
Type: or
Match: e but not f, g, h and i, or
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\w+` fails to distinguish `a` from `but` or `not`. It seems that you have to make comma a mandatory delimiter unless `and` is used and also define the `and` delimiter explicitly:

```
\w+(?:,\s*\w+(?:\s+and\s+\w+)?)+,?\s*(and|or)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/NqlBLk/1

Comment: +1 for using `?:`, I didn't think of that. It seems, I forgot to mention some aspects, sorry - I'll updated the question.