# Regex - Regular expression for repeat word with prefix

Tags: regex

How do I create a regular expression to match subword which start with same prefix, for example `aaa`, the random word after that has random length.

```
aaa[randomword1]aaa[randomword2]
```

If I use pattern

```
(aaa\w+)*
```

it match `(aaa)` and `[randomword1]aaa[randomword2]`. But I want to match groups: `aaa`, `randomword1`, `aaa`, `randomword2`.

EDIT: I mean in the string may have multi times `aaa`, and I need match all subword `aaa_randomword_times_n`.

Comment: You want a [non-greedy regex modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824302/how-to-make-regular-expression-into-non-greedy/2824314#2824314) for your sub-word pattern, i.e. `\w+?` instead of `\w+`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest `aaa(\w+)aaa(\w+)`, hope it will help you:)

Comment: How about 3, 4, etc. times `aaa` in the string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regular expression :

```
\b(aaa|(?<=\[).*?(?=\]))\b
```

> \b..\b -> zero-width assertion word boundary to match word
>
> aaa -> your specific word to look
>
> | -> check for optional
>
> (?<=[) look behind zero width assertion which checks characters after
>   open square bracket([)
>
> .*? : character to match
>
> (?=])) => look ahead zero width assertion which matches characters
>   before closing square bracket(])

Comment: Sorry but it not match, for example, `aaaSsdsaxczczaaaDsadasdaddxdsdfsdasaaaCvcxvcxv`.

Comment: I've posted regex based on input given in your question and it's working fine for that. With the help of above approach, you can formulate your own regex to meet your requirement.