# How to find multiple substrings between <> in one column in pandas data frame + python

Tags: python, regex, string, find, match

I am using Pandas and Python. My data is:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5],
                'Str':['aa <aafae><afre> ht4',
                       'v fef <><433>',
                       '<1234334> <a>',
                       '<bijf> 04<9tu0>q4g <vie>',
                       'aaa 1']})
```

I want to extract all the sub strings between < > and merge them with blank. For example, the above example should have the result:

```
aafae afre
  433
1234334 a
bijf 9tu0 vie
nan
```

So all the sub strings between < > are extracted. There will be nan if no such strings. I have already tried re library and str functions. But I am really new to regex. Could anyone help me out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pandas.Series.str.findall`:

```
a['Str'].str.findall('<(.*?)>').apply(' '.join)
```

Output:

```
0       aafae afre
1              433
2        1234334 a
3    bijf 9tu0 vie
4                 
Name: Str, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please also explain why we have to put ? after .*  ?  I did not do so. Then I can only find the last >, instead of the immediately next one.

Comment: @FengChen `?` is used to make regex _non greedy_: once it finds what it looks for it stops, rather than goes on until the last match. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824302/how-to-make-regular-expression-into-non-greedy will guide you better about what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this expression might work somewhat and to some extent:

```
import pandas as pd

a=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5],
                'Str':['aa <aafae><afre> ht4',
                       'v fef <><433>',
                       '<1234334> <a>',
                       '<bijf> 04<9tu0>q4g <vie>',
                       'aaa 1']})

a["new_str"]=a["Str"].str.replace(r'.*?<([^>]+)>|(?:.+)', r'\1 ',regex=True)

print(a)
```